# CMake throwing error with target_include_directories but works with include_directories

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I am creating a header only C++ library which depends on `jwt-cpp` by [Thalhammer](https://github.com/Thalhammer/jwt-cpp).

My CMake file is:

```
# Set CMake verison
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.2)

# Set name "tachyon" to variable {this} and assign that to the project
set(this this)
project(${this} LANGUAGES CXX)

# Set C++ compiling standards
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

# Add dependency libraries
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
include_directories(External/jwt/include)
include_directories(/opt/local/libexec/openssl3/include)

# Set subdirectory nomenclature
set(dir_external External)
set(dir_executables Executables)
set(dir_source Source)

# Set library nomenclature
set(LIB_NET_COMMONS lib_net_commons)

# Add subdirectories
add_subdirectory(${dir_external})
add_subdirectory(${dir_source})
add_subdirectory(${dir_executables})

# Add external dependencies
target_include_directories(${LIB_NET_COMMONS} INTERFACE External/jwt/include)

# Link libraries
target_link_libraries(${LIB_NET_COMMONS} INTERFACE jwt-cpp)
```

and my `lib.h` in `LIB_NET_COMMONS` includes `#include <jwt-cpp/jwt.h>`.

All this works perfectly but I am only using the external library in one target which is `LIB_NET_COMMONS` and I assuming only adding `target_include_directories(${LIB_NET_COMMONS} INTERFACE External/jwt/include)` should have been enough but if I don't include these two following lines in `CMakeLists.txt`

```
include_directories(External/jwt/include)
include_directories(/opt/local/libexec/openssl3/include)
```

it throws an error:

```
fatal error: 'jwt-cpp/jwt.h' file not found
#include <jwt-cpp/jwt.h>
```

Am I missing anything because adding the include path in `CMakeList.txt` for all targets when I need it only for one target seems unnecessary.

Edit: Adding [link to github repo](https://github.com/mjrusty/minimum-reproducible-cmake-include-directories-error) of `minimal reproducible example` for more context.

Comment: If you include header from LIB_NET_COMMONS that includes the external header `jwt.h`, it is the same as including `jwt.h` directly.

Comment: Use `-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` or other options to print actual compilation commands, check the difference and including path.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: `INTERFACE` means adding include directories for all **comsumers** of the library, but do NOT add them for the library itself. If you want to add include directories only for the library, use `PRIVATE` keyword. Since you don't provide the **complete** error message, we don't know the exact target which causes it, so we cannot help in choosing appropriate keyword.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried this but since the library in use is also an `INTERFACE`, I am not able to use `PRIVATE` here. I have added a minimum reproducible example in the edit if that helps.

Comment: The code referenced by you defines the **executable**, and most likely the error message is emitted when compile `main.cpp`. You link that executable with `INTERFACE` keyword (`target_link_libraries(${This} INTERFACE lib)`), so it doesn't obtain include directories from the library. Using `PRIVATE` keyword is perfectly allowable in that case.

Comment: The link [mcve] explicitly tells that relevant code should be **in the question post**, not linked: "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself".

Comment: What @Tsyvarev mentioned is the most likely answer to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a wild guess that could be confirmed if you would provide more information regarding how you structure your project and where are the individual targets defined (i.e. in which `CMakeLists.txt`).
**Try the following possible fix** to prove/disprove it i.e.:

Change the **relative path** in the `target_include_directories()` to an **absolute path** and see if it fixes the problem.

---

My hypothesis is based on how `include_directories()` works. It basically adds the included directory to **every target** in the current `CMakeLists.txt` and to every `CMakeLists.txt` that are added via `add_subdirectory()` this is also one of the reasons why the use of `include_directories()` is discouraged.

So what I think is happening is... that the actual path is (for example) `${dir_executables}/External/jwt/include` and because you use `include_directories()` it eventually adds the correct path to the include directories.

(Note it can be the opposite situation as well, that some of the targets need to go a level up in the directory tree to reach the folder)

EDIT: After checking the minimal reproducible example I will point to what Tsyvarev mentioned in the comments as the most likely culprit in this case. The executable doesn't "know" about the header files.

Comment: I tried adding the absolute path to the `target_include_directories()` but it still didn't work. I am attaching the link to `minimal reproducible example` for more context in this link: https://github.com/mjrusty/minimum-reproducible-cmake-include-directories-error. @Milan Š.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at it once I'm at a computer